# If $G$ is a group and $a,b$ are communting elements of $G$, then $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$ for all integers, $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

This is question 24 from Chapter 1.1 of Dummit&Foote’s Abstract Algebra.

Couple of questions with this, 1 verification of the proof. 2 Do I need to use induction for the negative powers as well or does it suffice as shown? 3 do i need to show that $a^{-1}b^{-1}$ commutes, if $ab$ does?

**PROOF**

Let $G$ be a group and let $a$ and $b$ be commuting elements of $G$, that is $ab = ba$.

**positive powers**

$(ab)^1=ab=a^1b^1$.
Assume that $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$.
Consider now $(ab)^{n+1}$.

$(ab)^{n+1}=(ab)(ab)^n=(ba)a^nb^n$ by commutativity and the induction hypothesis.

Therefore, $(ab)^{n+1}=ba^{n+1}b^n= a^{n+1}bb^n= a^{n+1}b^{n+1}$.

Hence $\forall n\in \mathbb{Z^+}, (ab)^n=a^nb^n$.

**zero power**

$(ab)^0=1=a^0b^0$.

**negative powers**

$\forall$ $-n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $-n<0$, $(ab)^{-n}=[(ab)^n]^{-1}$. Since $n>0$, we can apply the above result for positive powers.

Thus $[(ab)^n]^{-1}=(b^na^n)^{-1}=(a^n)^{-1}(b^n)^{-1}=a^{-n}b^{-n}$.

Therefore, $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$.

Comment: Looks right; well done.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin thank you.

Comment: If you haven't previously established it, it would probably require a separate inductive proof to show that if $a$ and $b$ commute, then $a^n$ and $b$ commute.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler good point. I actually did do that separately. However, I used that here without considering the need to establish it. Thanks.